# How to configure Apache on Ubuntu 14.04 if Nginx is already installed

Tags: 14.04, apache2, nginx

I followed the Tutorial on Digital Ocean and installed **LEMP** server successfully.

Then I read about reverse-proxy using Nginx and APache for hosting multiple websites on the same droplet .

Since I have Big fat droplet , I would like to host two Laravel Based APP on the same droplet .

So using this tutorial I Installed apache2 
[**LINK**](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-nginx-as-a-web-server-and-reverse-proxy-for-apache-on-one-ubuntu-14-04-droplet)

But unluckily apache is not running

```
$ sudo service apache2 reload
 * Reloading web server apache2                                               *
 * Apache2 is not running
```

So I did

```
 sudo netstat -tlpn
```

and got this table

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         Stat     e       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LIST     EN      5377/nginx
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LIST     EN      1233/sshd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LIST     EN      3529/mysqld
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LIST     EN      5377/nginx
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LIST     EN      1233/sshd
```

I am a windows user and I have no Idea about how to fix this .

Can any one help me out .

Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

Nginx runs on port 80 and that's ok. The default port for the Apache httpd is port 80, too and that's a problem.

Reconfigure Apache httpd

- Use port 8080 for your Apache httpd. Open `ports.conf`

  ```
  sudo nano vi /etc/apache2/ports.conf
  ```

  and replace

  ```
  Listen 80
  ```

  with

  ```
  Listen 8080
  ```

  Do the same for virtual hosts, if necessary.
- Restart Apache httpd

  ```
  sudo systemctl restart apache2
  ```

  or on Trusty with

  ```
  sudo service apache2 restart
  ```
- Check the output of `netstat`

  ```
  $ sudo netstat -tulpn | grep apache2
  tcp6   0  0 :::8080   :::*  LISTEN  22769/apache2
  ```

  And yes, also with the output above, httpd is listening on tcp port 80.
- Reconfigure nginx to work as proxy and use your Apache httpd as backend, e.g. for port 80 by editing of `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`

  ```
  sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
  ```

  and add the proxy settings below
  in the `location` section

  ```
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto http;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port 80;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  ```
- Restart nginx

  ```
  sudo systemctl restart nginx
  ```

  or on Trusty with

  ```
  sudo service nginx restart
  ```
- Check the output of `netstat`

  ```
  $ sudo netstat -tulpn | grep -P 'nginx|apache2'
  tcp  0  0 0.0.0.0:80  0.0.0.0:*  LISTEN  22973/nginx -g daem
  tcp6 0  0 :::80       :::*       LISTEN  22973/nginx -g daem
  tcp6 0  0 :::8080     :::*       LISTEN  22769/apache2
  ```

And it's a good idea to configure httpd to listen only on 127.0.0.1.

Comment: As an nginx expert, this is the way to go about it, temporarily stop nginx, install Apache, change Apache to be on a different port, start nginx.  :)

Comment: @ThomasW. Yes, of course. :)  But it's really necessary to stop nginx to install httpd?

Comment: Out Of The Box Installations of both Apache and nginx autodefault to Port 80 for "Out Of The Box" functionality.  There's no way around it - whether Apache or Nginx is installed first, you have to shut one off for `apt-get` to work right and configure the thing, then change one to be on a different port  and start the other one.  Otherwise you get fail to configure issues.

Comment: @ThomasW. I did not stop nginX while I was trying to install apache2 I think There is some error in that , Can you tell me how I can Roll back everything and do a fresh install  ?

Comment: Why a fresh install?

Answer (score -1):

Long story short - you have to run apache listening on different port (Listen), since port 80 is already in use by nginx.

Comment: This is the VERY basic explanation of what's going on; it would help if you gave an actual solution or method to fix this, rather than just say what the conflict is.